# How to add Ice Cream Sandwich virtual device?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I already have the android SDK and a few different virtual devices installed in eclipse. However, I cannot figure out how to get the other android versions. I want to install the Ice Cream Sandwich but I can't figure out how. Am I supposed to go to Help-->New Software and re-install everything or is there an easier way to just get 4.X?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the SDK-manager to install new platforms. Execute `android` from your `ANDROID_SDK/tools` folder *(or use `Window -> Android SDK manager` inside eclipse)*, select `android-4.0` from the list and click `Install packages`. Wait for the download to finish and close the manager. After that you should be able to create an android 4.0 emulator.

Comment: This list didn't automatically present itself. I downloaded a new sdk, then re-installed eclipse. Then I was able to update. I am not sure what the problem was, but it now seems to be updating properly and the 4.0 emulator is available.

Comment: Don't know, maybe your sdk was outdated or just refused to work out of the blue. Happens sometimes, had to reinstall my >1 year old sdk on windows a week ago too. Just didn't work out of nowhere and I got no clue why.

Answer (score 1):

You will first need to update to the latest version of the ADT plugin. After that has been completed, open the SDK manager and update the manager itself. You may already see an option to install the Android 4.0 SDK, but if not, it will be there after the SDK Manager and ADT tools have been updated. Select that option and wait for it to download and install. Then go to the AVD manager and create a new AVD, selecting Android 4.0 from the drop down list.